# most efficient way to return values of dict in a list on a pre-determine order

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

assuming that I have a dictionary such has:

```
x = {'a':1, 'c':4, 'b':5, 'z':3}
```

what would be the most efficient way to return a list (or numpy 1-D array) of pre-determine key order. I want the list to look be in this order -> [a,b,c,z] i.e.

```
[1, 5, 4, 3]
```

thanks!

Comment: Store the keys in a list, iterate over the list and retrieve the keys. E.g. `order = ["a", "b", "c", "z"]; items = [x[key] for key in order]`

Comment: @kindall that make sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer here is "hidden" in the comments:

> Store the keys in a list, iterate over the list and retrieve the keys:

`order = ["a", "b", "c", "z"]; items = [x[key] for key in order]` ( provided by  kindall )

Comment: yes, after some non-scientific speed run, this one seems to perform the best

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "*the most efficient way*" (since I don't know what cost you are trying to optimize), but here is one way:

```
x = {'a':1, 'c':4, 'b':5, 'z':3}
y = list(map(x.get, sorted(x)))
print(y)
```

Here is another choice:

```
y = [v for k,v in sorted(x.items())]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. The simplest would be using an OrderedDict, which you could read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key).

Another would be to have a separate list of the keys. You could iterate through that list, getting the corresponding values from the dictionary, and appending them to a new list. This would give you the values in the order you want. Let me know if you would like an example of this.

(Speed-wise, I believe OrderedDict would run the best, the second option would be O(N).)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach which first sorts the keys, then retrieves the values.

```
In [51]: [x[el] for el in sorted(list(x.keys()))]
Out[51]: [1, 5, 4, 3]
```